# Analyze VS2010 C# projects and report files on disk not part of the projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, mercurial

I discovered earlier tonight that files and folders I have removed from my C# projects are apparently still on disk, even though my Visual Studio Mercurial plugin seems to do a good job of deleting them when I delete them in Visual Studio. It must have hickuped when it came to these files.

So I wondered... Does anyone have a script or similar, or know of something, that will look at my .csproj files and report extra files and folders on my disk that isn't part of the project files?

I just want to clean up my repository contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to go to the Project menu and choose "Show All Files".

This option is set on a per-project basis.

Comment: Thanks both of you, there was quite a few files leftover from my Subversion to Mercurial migration process - http://hg.vkarlsen.no/hgweb.cgi/LVK-for-NET/rev/dd0176b775e8

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the "Show All Files" option in the solution explorer, any files not included in the project file will be shown with white icons.

[alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/9986/85818429.png](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/9986/85818429.png)

If you then fully expand the project tree, you should be able to see any file that is not included in the project. Additionally, you will also be able to see any files that are included in the project but are not present on disk (these will have a warning triangle overlaid onto them).

This is a per-project setting, so you will have to do it for each of your projects.